# Client ID and Client secret to access foursquare api

Tags: api, foursquare

I am going to access foursquare api. As I was going through their documentation,I am going to use 
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search service to serach for the venues.

To use this api we need client id and secret and has to be appended in the above URL.
But how to get this client id and scret. Should I register my app in the foursquare site.
Is the following url correct for registering the app:

https://foursquare.com/developers/register

If it is correct,it is asking for the app market id. Our application is not in any of the app market because it is an enterprise app.So in that case how to get client id and client secret??

Kindly help.

Comment: Kindly reply as I need to integrate it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can complete the form without inputting details about App Market IDs by simply hitting the 'Save Changes' button (the App Market fields are not validated on submit). This will bring you to a screen that contains your client id & secret.

Comment: Yes. Later I tried without supplying app market id and just provided welcome url(mandatory field) and it generated client id and secret. But is welcome url validated?I mean, in creating app, I just provided fake welcome url and it created client id and secret. Then what is the motto in providing welcome url??

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but if nothing else it gives Foursquare a way of tracking what people are building with their API.

Comment: The market IDs are used if your app is in any of the native app marketplaces. Since people use the Foursquare API to create web apps as well, these are not required.

You can supply dummy web addresses while testing (e.g., pointing to your development environment), but you ought to change them to real addresses when going into production.

Comment: Thanks for givinng your view.One point I want to know that what ip address api.foursquare.com use?I mean it is static or it changes its ip address dynamically or is there any range?Because I have to test these services and needs to do the dns entry to access api.foursquare.com